# Establish plink ssh connection via tramp to AWS instance

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp

on my freaking company windows machine I am trying to use tramp to connect to my aws instance.

On pressing C-x C-f, on linux I usually did press slash twice to erase the path and the put in: ssh:....

But on windows I cannot use double slash or double backslash to delete the c:\ part of the path to input "plink:..."

How can I make this work please?

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's a typo when you write "on linux I usually did press backslash twice". Like you mean the slash `/` key.

This doesn't work on MS Windows indeed. Emacs on MS Windows supports UNC file names. That is, if you have mounted a network drive `share` on your machine, you can access the respective directory in Emacs as `//share/...`. That's why the leading two slashes `//` are always kept when you try file name completion in the minibuffer. You must delete the slash with the backspace key `←` on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the answer.  I also use tramp with plink on windows.  After some similar frustrations I started using counsel-tramp as shown below.  Since I adopted this method it has always worked well.  Counsel-tramp is an additional library that needs to be installed (I already was using Ivy and related libraries).

```
(setq tramp-default-method "plink")
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c t") 'counsel-tramp)
(setq counsel-tramp-custom-connections '(/plink:ian@host1.xx:~/
                     /plink:host1.xx|sudo::/
                     /plink:admin@host2.com:~/
                     /plink:hostshortcut:~/
                     /plink:hostshortcut2:~/
                     /plink:hostshortcut3:~/
                     /plink:hostshortcut4:~/))
```